# Can I limit the key-values ​of a Redux state?

Tags: redux, state, key-value

Im gona super-minimalize the example:

Typical Redux initialState:

```
const initialState = {
    user: {
    city: 'newYork'
    }
}
```

Imagine the response to my api is something like this:

```
user: {
    city: 'newYork',
    createdAt: "32132131",
    updatedAt: "332313213",
    }
```

So I have the typical action:

```
export const setState = (state) => {
    return {
      type: 'SET_STATE',
      payload: state     
    }
}
```

With the typical Reducer:

```
case 'SET_STATE':      
  return {
    ...state,
    user: action.payload
  }
```

The question is: can I somehow prevent the "createdAt and updatedAt" attributes from being created?

Of course i know i can do it one bye one like:

```
case 'SET_STATE':      
  return {
    ...state,
    user: { city: action.payload.city }
  }
```

But this is not fair if i have tons of atributes.

And, of course i know i can prepare the output from the server, but still not fair using "select city from users... "... cause i have tons of atributes.

Im asking if there some way to limit the attributes to only those that I have created in the initial state.

It seems silly but it would save a lot of unnecessary memory space (and time)

Comment: i have openMind and i can change of using or not using Redux.

Comment: server: Laravel 8

Comment: Do it one by one. It's good to be explicit about what the store holds.